# Issues with plotting coordinates ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping, ggmap

I have been trying to get the following dataset to map using ggmap and ggplot2 combination.

my dataframe -> head(dt.fil) containing 855 values

```
        lat     lon        airline
1  -73.9930 40.7480 Virgin America
2  -71.0200 42.3610 Virgin America
3 -118.4062 33.9454 Virgin America
4 -118.4041 33.9421 Virgin America
5  -96.9322 33.2145 US Airways
6 -118.3859 34.0220 United
```

my code is the following

```
map_airlines <- get_map(location = c(lon = mean(dt.fil$lon),
                                     lat = mean(dt.fil$lat)), zoom = 5,
                        maptype = "satellite", scale = 2)

# visualze the tweet locations
ggmap(map_airlines) +
  geom_point(data=dt.fil, aes(x=lon, y=lat, fill='red',
                              alpha=0.6, colour=airline)) +
  guides(fill=FALSE, alpha=FALSE)
```

I get the following errors

```
Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
5: Removed 835 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

I would really appreciate if somebody could help me with this :)

Comment: These are not errors, only warnings. Do you get any output?

Comment: This may not be related to the warning messages. But you want to move `fill='red'` and `alpha=0.6` outside of `aes()`.

Comment: @DCZ yes i do get an output, its an empty map with no coordinates and no map, blank rectangle
jazzurro thank you for feedback i will change that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues here:

1. First of all, valid latitudes go from -90 up to +90 while valid longitudes go from -180 up to +180. Seeing as your latitudes don't fall in this range, i suppose you switched them. Therefore, in the rest of this example, I changed latitude into longitude and longitude into latitude. (Seeing as you're working with American airlines and datapoints are all located in the USA, this seemed reasonable).

   ```
   lon <- c(-73.9930 , -71.0200 , -118.4062 , -118.4041, -96.9322 , -118.3859 )
   lat <- c(40.7480,  42.3610 , 33.9454 , 33.9421 , 33.2145 , 34.0220 )
   airline <- c("Virgin America", "Virgin America", "Virgin America", "Virgin America", "US Airways", "United")
   dt.fil <- data.frame(lat, lon, airline)
   ```
2. The second problem is that your map is not large enough for the points to be plotted. To solve this, just adjust the zoom. (i took 3 instead of 5, just adjust it untill all datapoints fit).

   ```
   map_airlines <- get_map(location = c(lon = mean(dt.fil$lon),
                                lat = mean(dt.fil$lat)),
                   zoom = 3,
                   maptype = "satellite", scale = 2)

   #visualze the tweet locations
   ggmap(map_airlines) +
   geom_point(data=dt.fil, aes(x=lon, y=lat, colour=airline), fill='red',
        alpha=0.6) +
   guides(fill=FALSE, alpha=FALSE)
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, this helped a lot!! :)